# How to validate a Bayesian result?

Tags: bayesian, validation

I'm trying to link statistical analysis methods to validable business observations. Ideally an interpretation that is measureable and can objectively rank success of predictions.

For the frequentist p-value of 0.95 I figured the statement is:
There are instances - some of which have a real effect and some are purely random (according to some agreed notion of randomness). Amongst the purely random instances, this frequentist will misclassify 5% as having an effect. (Nothing else can be said?)
I think I can assume that p-value statements transfer to a set of instances, even if it's completely different experiments(?). No need for repeatable experiments.

Is this correct so far?

What's an equivalent statement for Bayesian results? It should be something measureable.